# i am creating a multi-client chat application in python using socket

Tags: python, sockets, serversocket

There is an error while encoding the string on the server side. It is throwing the following error:

> broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8")) TypeError: encoding without a string
>   argument

Here is my code

```
msg = "%s from  has joined the chat!",name
broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
```

Although I am encoding it with string arguments.
Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If `name` is a string and you write `msg = "%s from  has joined the chat!",name`, you will receive a tuple of strings, first element is "%s from  has joined the chat!", second - value of name string.

For joining strings try:

```
 msg = "%s from  has joined the chat!" + name
```

or in this case maybe:

```
msg = name + "has joined the chat!"
```

Comment: Or using python 3.6 f-string, that would be something like

`msg = f'{name} has joind the chat!'`

Answer (score 0):

`bytes()` doesnt work with strings made with % formatting, you can format using:

```
msg = "{} from has joined the chat!".format(name)
```

or from python 3.6:

```
msg = f"{name} from has joined the chat!"
```

This is because in your code `msg` is actually a tuple (try looking at `type(msg)`), functions like `print()` can convert that tuple into a string but `bytes()` does not do that

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this

```
msg = "%s from  has joined the chat!",name
```

with this

```
msg = "%s from  has joined the chat!" % name
```

and this

```
broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
```

with this

```
broadcast(msg.encode("utf8"))
```

that's all